# Find all polygons that result from more than 1 lines intersecting a square

Tags: algorithm, geometry, line

I am afraid I have kind of hit a wall.. my math skills ain't helping me either.
So my problem is the following:
 I have 4 points lets say [(-1,1)(1,1)(-1,-1)(1,-1)] that make up a square. Now image I also have 2-5 lines that intersect with the square and with each other as well. Do you guys have any advice on how I can find find all polygons (their points) that results from cutting up the square ?

Again thank you very much.

Comment: What do you mean by "find all polygons (their points) that results from cutting up the square"? all combinaison of all intersections?

Comment: If you can solve "split N-gon with single line" then you can just do this iteratively.

Comment: @kepotx Well after the lines intersect the square new N-gons will be created. Triangles, squares, pentagons, exagons etc... I need to know which those N-gons are by getting the set of points that make them up. The set of points being the original 4 points plus all the new intersections points .

Comment: Add an example with input (e.g. 2 lines) and expected output? This would clarify the question.